# snakemake target rule as variable for python code

Tags: python, snakemake, directed-acyclic-graphs, orchestration

I have a snakemake workflow that does a lot of work before it reaches the definition of the rules (querying files, accessing databases, filtering a data frame). Not all of this work is necessary, depending on the target rule I want to invoke.

How can I know which target rule is selected on the command line? Then I could have the pure-python work done upfront be limited to only what is necessary for that target rule.

Desired example, for which I need to know if the "snakemake.target_rule" variable exists and which variable it actually is:

```py
def do_work_for_target_a():
    lots_of_work()
    return table

def do_work_for_target_b():
    lots_of_work()
    return table

if snakemake.target_rule == 'a':
   table_a = do_work_for_target_a()
elif snakemake.target_rule === 'b':
   table_b = do_work_for_target_b()
else:
   table_a = do_work_for_target_a()
   table_b = do_work_for_target_b()

rule all:
   input:
       "output_a.txt",
       "output_b.txt",

rule a:
   input:
       "output_a.txt",


rule b:
   input:
       "output_b.txt",
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but a workaround that achieves the same result. The main idea is to create a temporary file whose only purpose is to run the rule-specific preparations:

```py
def do_work_for_target_a():
    lots_of_work()

def do_work_for_target_b():
    lots_of_work()

rule all:
   input:
       "output_a.txt",
       "output_b.txt",

rule pre_a:
   output: temp("pre_a.txt")
   run:
      do_work_for_target_a()

rule pre_b:
   output: temp("pre_b.txt")
   run:
      do_work_for_target_b()


rule a:
   input:
       "pre_a.txt",
       "output_a.txt",

rule b:
   input:
       "pre_b.txt",
       "output_b.txt",
```

Comment: Thanks! I have minimally edited my example, in the sense that the do_work() functions actually return a DataFrame, which is used by the rest of the rules. Am I wrong in thinking that with your strategy it is not possible to create variables? But I could still write things to files and open these later, I guess.

Comment: Ah, I see, it might be possible to achieve what you are after, but not with my hack.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I know which target rule is selected on the command line

A quite crude solution could be to parse the `sys.argv` list and determine the target rule. I'm not sure how to implement this robustly though.

Comment: Hmmm I could just do "`if "a" in sys.argv`... That isn't that bad. Not robust, but workable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any intended way to access the name of the target rule name(s) from the CLI inside the `Snakefile` either.

As a workaround I suggest passing an additional `--config` value with the `snakemake` call, e.g. `snakemake --config prep_for=<a|b> -- <remainder of your snakemake call>` and make the modifications to your `Snakefile` to access that config value:

```py
def do_work_for_target_a():
    lots_of_work()
    return table

def do_work_for_target_b():
    lots_of_work()
    return table

if config.prep_for == 'a':
   table_a = do_work_for_target_a()
elif config.prep_for === 'b':
   table_b = do_work_for_target_b()
else:
   table_a = do_work_for_target_a()
   table_b = do_work_for_target_b()

...
```

Comment: Aha, yes, that would work. Some extra work on the cli to specify the target twice, but not too bad. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I'd also prefer to avoid the redundancy, but I haven't found anything in the snakemake object to point to the target rule (could also be confusing if you have multiple target rules or specify the targets by filename)